# unable to download ADT plugin

Tags: android, eclipse

I've followed instructions on developer.android.com carefully:

I've downloaded Eclipse Classic 3.6.1
I've opened Help->Install New Software and added ADT Plugin site
But it failed twice once using 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and the other time using 
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

now as i try to do it repeat the process, it says duplicate(it is duplicate) and devoid's me of downloading adt plugin.
now how can i download adt plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always uninstall installed plugin by doing: `Help` -> `About Eclipse` - > `Installation Details` -> `Installed Software`. There you can select the `Android Developer Tools` and uninstall it.

That way you will get another chance of installing. If you want me to help you installing afterwards you need to share what error do you get.